# How to make people login to use the internet

Tags: wireless-router, login, internet-connection

I want people to login to my sky router like you do in cafes and some places with free wifi. (e.g Wifi powered by the cloud)

I want to do this as I would like to put web restrictions on different users. For example one account (Named "foo") gets access to everything. But the other account (Named "foo2") only gets access to a quarter of things.

Comment: "Walled garden" is the search term you're looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's called "Captive Portal" or "Authentication Page"
you have a lot of ways to do that

- Flash your router with a new Firmware dd-wrt or open-wrt or tomato. "Normal"
- or buy a new router like UBNT Ubiquity they made it for this propose. "Easy"
- or you can setup a server "old PC" to make something called RADIUS
  server. "Hard"